# Low level table creation on a USB memory stick

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have been scammed by a USB stick supplier. The file table is incorrectly set up to show the size you think you purchased. When you try to write to the device, it seems to work as the directory shows up but since the storage memory is not what the (say) FAT 32 table indicates, your data is corrupt and never comes back.

I can possibly use this chips for some other things if I can look at the real storage capability and fix the File Control Blocks to be accurate. I have opened up some of the sticks but they put epoxy over the internal components so I cannot research the manufacturers.

I am an experienced low lever programmer and device driver writer. I actually wrote the first Norton AntiVirus software with Peter Norton back in the early 90's. I have no experience with USB memory stick technology however.

What software tools or hardware interfaces do I need to set up to get at and program the interface? Any training / learning documents as well?

Comment: What do the drives show for capacity if you try to partition them with  (for example) Linux fdisk/cfdisk?  It may just be a matter of wiping out the partition table and creating a new partition table and filesystems.

Comment: @killermist, I think that is exactly the problem, that the device is reporting for example 32GB to the system (i.e., the BIOS, `fdisk`, etc.) but actually only has, say 1GB. As such, re-partitioning won’t help. (Besides, taking the post at face value, I would think that someone who helped write the first Norton anti-virus would have considered re-partitioning.)

Comment: @Synetech  Well, you never know.  I've often tried all kinds of things to fix something when later someone pointed out something super-simple, and it was exactly the right thing.

Comment: Even if the drive itself is reporting wrong capacity you could just create a small partition at the beginning, where the sectors are available.

Comment: Hardware interface, a hammer;)